# How to copy files to folders with same name by comparing file names with folder names?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to compare the file and folder names which are in the same folder to copy files to folders with same names.

For now this is my code:

Test file/folder names:
sth(folder)  sth2.fastq  sth.fastq

```
for fname in *.fastq; do
    for f in */; do
        if "${fname%.*}"=="$f"; then
            -exec cp $fname /${f} \;
        fi
    done
done
```

When I run the code I got this error:

./script.sh: line 3: sth2==sth/: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 3: sth==sth/: No such file or directory

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say something like that :

```
for fname in *.fastq; do
    #Getting rid of the extension
    locfname=${fname%.*}
    #Getting rid of numbers if any
    locdirname=${locfname//[0-9]*}
    #Creating the directory if it doesn't exist
    if [[ ! -d $locdirname ]]; then
        mkdir $locdirname
    fi
    #Moving file in the proper directory (can use cp instead)
    mv $fname $locdirname
done
```

Hope it might help

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you so much for your answer. I used your code as: for fname in *.fastq; do
    locfname=${fname%.*}
    if [[ ! -d $locfname ]]; then
        mkdir $locfname
    fi
    mv $fname $locfname
done